# python, django : python-decouple occur not found error

Tags: python, django

I'm using django and need to decouple setting data from source code,

because setting information must be hidden.

so tried python-decouple module.

I tried .ini and .env file both.

when using setting.ini file, I located it next to setting.py(same directory)

when using setting.env, located setting.py's parent derictory.

both occur error like this.

```
SECREAT_KEY not found. Declare it as envvar or define a default value.
```

setting.ini file

```
[settings]
SECRET_KEY=1234
```

setting.env file

```
SECRET_KEY=1234
```

source code in setting.py

```
from decouple import config

SECRET_KEY = config('SECRET_KEY')
```

I already installed python-decouple

```
pip install python-decouple
```

how can I fix it?

please help me

os = window

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.

reson was .ini file's name.

file name must be **settings.ini** and my file name was setting.ini

Answer (score 0):

To be honest I don't see the need for a special module for this. You could just as well create a py file next to the settings.py file (I tend to name it something like **local_settins.py**), add your settings and secrets to that file, then just add `from local_settings import *` to settings.py. But I guess everyone has their own preference. :)

Comment: thank you for your comment! I need to upload this project to github. so i read  that in this situation python-decouple modlue is good choice.

Comment: I thought you might be thinking of way not to commit secrets to git. You can do that using my way I mentioned above and just add the **local_setting.py** (or whatever you choose to name it) to **.gitignore**.
Then you'll have one less module to think about that is just complicating a simple problem.

Comment: thank you very much now I understand perfectly ! I couldn't think about using less module.